# Difference between ResizeMode and AlignSelf For Image?

Tags: image, react-native, stylesheet

So, for an `Image` in `react-native`, one can set `alignSelf` in a `StyleSheet` or one can use `resizeMode` in the `Image` tag. What's the difference in usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of it is, that you have to mentally separate the View - or 'box' in css box model terms - and the rendered image it contains. All the styling you define applies to the box. The resizeMode determines how the actual image data is rendered into that box.

Answer (score 1):

[AlignSelf](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-self) defines how the image is placed within the parent container and makes possible to override the align-items value for specific flex items.

ResizeMode is similar to css [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) and defined how the image should fill its own container.